# tkinter entry widget that takes in images

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a Tkinter interface for a program I just wrote. The interface needs to have a widget where the user can insert an image for the program to process. I couldn't find such a widget online. How would I make such an interface?

Comment: You mean a file chooser dialog? Look at [`askopenfilename`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of tkinter entry widget that takes in images right away:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
    import tkinter.filedialog as tkfd
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkFileDialog as tkfd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.pack()
    path = tkfd.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file",
                    filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
    entry.insert('0', path)
    root.mainloop()
```